# Kivy image widget does not update image

Tags: python, image, opencv, kivy

I am currently reading a file using imread in the opencv package for python. I do some editing, and then I save the file with a different name, which for convenience say "test.png". I then load this file and display it using the Kivy image widget. All of this works.

However, when I try to edit another image file and save it under the same name "test.png", then load and display it to the Kivy widget, the new file does not seem to ever get read. Opencv imwrite operation seems to work and the file is there. But kivy seems to load previous version of the file. Even when I try to save files with multiple names, Kivy seems to only display the original files, and not the rewritten versions.

So my question is whether Kivy caches the images? If it does, is there a way around it?

Comment: Have you tried `image.reload()` ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I got sidetracked. I ended up going with clearing the cache and re-reading the image.  I will try this today and let you know.